# How to find the number of solutions to the equation $\frac {50}{x} + \frac {126}{y} = 1$ , assuming that x and y are positive, integer numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Find the number of solutions to the equation $\frac {50}{x} + \frac {126}{y} = 1$ , assuming that both $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Is this the entire question? Or was there another part to this?

Comment: For starters $x = 100$ and $y = 252$. These are just one example of the possibly infinite solutions to your problem.

Comment: yes, this is the entire question @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: Where did you receive this question?

Comment: but x and y are integers, so I guess there must be some limit to the number of solutions? this question is taken from the past stage of maths contest organised by uni in Poland @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: Did you check the answer? Well now thinking of it I realize that there are finite solutions but the range of solutions is large enough that it can not be cracked by brute force (the integer part is all that matters).

Comment: I am sorry to not have noticed the word integer. The problem seems to be quite beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing fractions you have $$50y+126x=xy$$ which can be rewritten $$(x-50)(y-126)=6300$$

For every integer factorisation  $ab=6300$ you have a solution with $x=a+50$. Count with care.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: write $$x=\frac{50y}{y-126}$$
and this can be written as $$x=\frac{6300}{y-126}+50$$

Answer (score 0):

There are 54 possible pairs (x,y) satisfying your equation. Multiply  your equation by xy to get 50y + 126x = xy. This equation is equivalent to (x-50)(y-126)= 6300. Since there are 54 positive divisors of 6300 and for each integer factorization of 6300 = ab we get x=50+a, y=126+b there are a total of 54 possible solutions.